# Rabbit cluster loadbalancing, and HA what the difference?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a three node cluster but did not to the reliable queue.  I am using puka for python as the client.

For load balancing on ec2 I am using route53 and assign an equal weight to a private ip address.  So..if I have three ec2 instances I have 3 route53 entries.

So...my question is this why the cluster?  What is the difference with three nodes not clustered on route53 versus three nodes clustered on route53?  Are all rabbits writable and readable?

My understaing is that if I want HA and reliable queues then rabbit becomes a master slave and a working cluster is required first before turing the custer into reliable queues.

I am rather confused about how to best cluster and the differences between a cluster vs HA.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Clustered nodes will have equally weighted nodes, that no master and no slave, the only advantage is that when a publisher pushes a message to some queue located on other node, the message will traverse from node to node (through Erlang's clustered VM layer) to reach its consumer/worker.

On the other hand, in the HA mode, All queues and exchanges (as per some policy you specify) will be replicated across all the nodes, more over, there is only one master and one or more slaves, where the master is the oldest existing node, and when it dies the second oldest node will take over and be the master.

Let me know if that was the answer you expected.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://insidethecpu.com/2014/11/17/load-balancing-a-rabbitmq-cluster/) is an article outlining both HA and load-balancing techniques, and how to combine the two efficiently, across a RabbitMQ cluster.